# How I can add Rewrite rule in htaccess only for home page?

Tags: apache-http-server, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have a problem with apache.

My site has these rules now:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysqite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* path/to/html/my.html [L]
```

I need create rules only for home page for redirect to another html file. How I can to do this?

Old rule must work for other site pages.

I try this, but it is not work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysqite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ path/to/html/my-new.html [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysqite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) path/to/html/my.html [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you would like to change the default index page so that when the visitors open http://mysqite.com, my.html would come up, you can try this in the .htaccess file:

DirectoryIndex my.html

No rewrite is required.

---

Edit:

Sorry I missed your point about the existing rules.
You can write the rules like this:

> RewriteRule ^$ /path/to/html/my-new.html [L]
>
> RewriteRule !^/path/to/html/my-new.html$ path/to/html/my.html [L]

So you are basically telling it to redirect the requests with the hostname only to my-new.html, and everything else to my.html. The second line explicitly excludes the my-new.html request. If it is not specified explicitly, when the rewrite of the first line is executed, it will trigger the second line and eventually everything will be redirected to my.html.

Comment: It works, okay, thanks, but how I can rewrite to other pages?

Comment: Sorry I missed part of your question. I modified the answer above, please check.

Comment: Thanx! It works!!!